# Getting updated context

Tags: reactjs

How can I make the child component gets an updated context from the parent? I am passing ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs['something']).offsetWidth and I want the child to get the updated value when the width changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind to [onresize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize) event. Something like the code below should do the trick.

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {offsetWidth: this.offsetWidth()};

    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize.bind(this));
  }

  offsetWidth() {
    return ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs['something']).offsetWidth;
  }

  onResize() {
    this.setState({offsetWidth: this.offsetWidth()});
  }

  render() {
    const {offsetWidth} = this.state;
    return (
      <Child offsetWidth={offsetWidth}/>
    );
  }
}
```